# How to save env variable in osX in django

Tags: python, django, environment

this might occur as a naive question. I am using cookie cutter django template and have to set env variables every time restarts the project.

I am doing the following every time I start working on the project

> export env_var_for_project=some_value

What I need to do in order to have these variables stored so that I don't have to export every time I open up my project

Comment: Depends on how you start the project. If from a shell, you can set the envvars in a shell login file (which depends on the shell being used).

Comment: It depends, most of the time I use zsh to access my projects.

Comment: You can add them at the bottom of your `.zshrc` file (in your home directory) then, just as you enter them now (one per line). Start a new terminal once you're done editing `.zshrc`, and you should be good for the future.

Comment: Thanks, @9769953, will try that! Appreciate your replies

Answer (score 0):

You can use a module called [`dotenv`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/). Then create a `.env` file in your project with all the environment variables you need and then use them by importing the module and accessing them with `os.environ`.

For example, if your `.env` file has the following content:

```
MY_API_KEY=xxxxxxx
```

To use it, call `load_dotenv()` and access it from `os.environ`:

```py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()


MY_API_KEY = os.environ['MY_API_KEY']
```